# Android: Custom view fails to instantiate

Tags: android, android-custom-view, instantiation

I am trying to add Smaato to my app to monotize it. I have been following the [developers guide](http://nkonecny.com/smaato.pdf) but I keep getting the error that my custom view for the banner isn't being instantiated. I have the custom view wrapped in a relative layout:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" android:id="@+id/adcontainer"
    android:layout_height="50dip" android:background="#666">
        <com.smaato.SOMA.SOMABanner android:id="@+id/BannerView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dip" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I follow the other steps, but no where does it seem to show how to instantiate the view. Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`com.smaato.SOMA.SOMABanner` must be a public class with a constructor `public SOMABanner(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet)`.

Comment: Sorry, I am still new to android could you expand? public SOMABanner(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){ //What goes here?
}

Comment: Usually attributes are retrieved here. But if your view doesn't need to parse attributes you can just call `super(context, attrs)`.

Comment: Here's an implementation of this constructor for `LinearLayout`: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/frameworks/base.git;a=blob;f=core/java/android/widget/LinearLayout.java;h=faf082dcd9c6201a9556267546ff61965869fbae;hb=HEAD#l119

Answer (score 2):

Although this wasn't the problem here I had a similar issue because I wasn't passing the AttributeSet to my custom view and eclipse couldn't find the appropriate constructor.

Whatever your class is make sure it has a constructor that matches the signature:

```
public MyClass(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){}
```

Comment: This is useful information, but it is not an attempt to answer the original question. As such, it should be posted as a comment rather than an answer. Although you can't add comments (except on your posts) until you reach 50 reputation, you should still refrain from posting comments as answers.